# PPT VBA, attempting to import images from a URL whose picture filename changes based on date/time

Tags: vba, url, powerpoint

Below is my code; I'm current visiting the website I want to get images from and DL'ing them into a folder on my desktop and importing the images that way into the PPT using below code.

**But** I want to remove that step, I'm wondering if VBA can grab the images directly from the website. But I've noticed that the img url changes w/ time.

I.E. :
https://www.fnmoc.navy.mil/wxmap_cgi/dynamic/GFS/2021110806/gfs10.wav.000.go_mex.gif
tomorrow will be
https://www.fnmoc.navy.mil/wxmap_cgi/dynamic/GFS/2021110906/gfs10.wav.000.go_mex.gif

so its not as simple as doing

```
  'Sat_image.
  ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture( _
   FileName:="https://www.fnmoc.navy.mil/wxmap_cgi/dynamic/GFS/2021110806/gfs10.wav.000.go_mex.gif", _
   LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
   SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=0, Top:=74.30732, _
   Width:=358.5, Height:=218.5972).Select
   With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
   .ZOrder msoSendToBack
   End With
```

Since this requires editing my VBA code to the new image URL everyday. Is there a clever way to tackle this problem? Any suggestions?

**Current Setup:**

```
  'Sat_image.
  ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture( _
   FileName:="C:\Users\User\Desktop\New folder\1.gif", _
   LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
   SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=0, Top:=74.30732, _
   Width:=358.5, Height:=218.5972).Select
   With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
   .ZOrder msoSendToBack
   End With
   'Top_left.
  ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture( _
   FileName:="C:\Users\User\Desktop\New folder\2", _
   LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
   SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=337.3333, Top:=58, _
   Width:=401.3334, Height:=262.6668).Select
   With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
  .PictureFormat.CropLeft = 45
  .PictureFormat.CropTop = 31
  .PictureFormat.CropRight = 34
  .PictureFormat.CropBottom = 60
  .ZOrder msoSendToBack
  End With
   'Bottom_left.
  ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture( _
   FileName:="C:\Users\User\Desktop\New folder\3", _
   LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
   SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=-24.23079, Top:=280.1251, _
   Width:=400.8461, Height:=262.6441).Select
   With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
  .PictureFormat.CropLeft = 45
  .PictureFormat.CropTop = 31
  .PictureFormat.CropRight = 32
  .PictureFormat.CropBottom = 60
  .ZOrder msoSendToBack
  End With
   'Bottom_right.
  ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture( _
   FileName:="C:\Users\User\Desktop\New folder\4", _
   LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
   SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=337.1539, Top:=280.125, _
   Width:=400.1539, Height:=262.6441).Select
   With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
  .PictureFormat.CropLeft = 45
  .PictureFormat.CropTop = 31
  .PictureFormat.CropRight = 32
  .PictureFormat.CropBottom = 60
  .ZOrder msoSendToBack
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: How do I do that, sorry

Comment: Hint for your question: `Format$(Date,"yyyymmdd06")`

Comment: Ben, ty. Can i have another hint pls?

Comment: Wondering if the solution looks something like this, but this doesn't work. ```FileName:="https://www.fnmoc.navy.mil/wxmap_cgi/dynamic/GFS/Format$(Now,YYYYMMDD)/gfs10.wav.000.go_mex.gif", _```

Comment: `FileName:="https://www.fnmoc.navy.mil/wxmap_cgi/dynamic/GFS/" & Format$(Now,YYYYMMDD) & "/gfs10.wav.000.go_mex.gif"`

Comment: I think you want `"yyyymmdd06"` based on the sample URLs you've provided.

Comment: Im so close, I feel it! Run time error "specific file wasn't found" ```FileName:="https://www.fnmoc.navy.mil/wxmap_cgi/dynamic/GFS/" & Format$(Date, YYYYMMDD06) & "/gfs10.wav.000.go_mex.gif", _```

Comment: Why do you not have quotes `"` around `YYYMMDD06`?

Comment: got it to work! ```FileName:="https://www.fnmoc.navy.mil/wxmap_cgi/dynamic/GFS/" & Format$(Date, "YYYYMMDD00") & "/gfs10.wav.012.go_mex.gif", _```